# Commutator of the power of two elements

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $T_1,T_2\in \cal{A}$ with $\cal{A}$ is an algebra.

> Let $n_1,n_2\in \mathbb{N}$. Is it true that
>   $$[T_1^{n_1},T_2^{n_2}]=\displaystyle\sum_{\substack{\alpha+\alpha'=n_1-1 \\ \beta +\beta'=n_2-1}}T_1^{\alpha}T_2^{\beta}[T_1,T_2]T_2^{\alpha'}T_1^{\beta'}?$$

If the formula is false, is it possible to establish a relationship between $[T_1^{n_1},T_2^{n_2}]$ and $[T_1,T_2]$?

Comment: Certainly not as written: you'd want $T_1^{\alpha'}$ and $T_2^{\beta'}$ so each term has $n_1$ $T_1$'s and $n_2$ $T_2$'s.

Comment: This is pure algebra, nothing of functional analysis or Banach theory...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First try the case $n_2 = 1$:

$$\eqalign{[T_1^{n_1}, T_2] &= \sum_{j=0}^{n_1-1} (T_1^{n_1-j} T_2 T_1^{j} - T_1^{n_1-j-1} T_2 T_1^{j+1})\cr
&= \sum_{j=0}^{n_1-1} T_1^{n_1-j-1} [T_1,T_2] T_1^{j}}$$
Similarly,
$$ [T_1, T_2^{n_2}] = \sum_{k=0}^{n_2-1} T_2^{n_2-k-1} [T_1,T_2] T_2^{k}$$
Substituting $T_2^{n_2}$ for $T_2$ in the first formula and using the second,
$$[T_1^{n_1}, T_2^{n_2}] = \sum_{j=0}^{n_1-1} \sum_{k=0}^{n_2-1} T_1^{n_1-j-1} T_2^{n_2-k-1} [T_1,T_2] T_2^k T_1^j $$